# Problem with "~" in routing file instead of ".."

Tags: asp.net, webforms, scriptbundle

I'm working on a asp.net web-form website in which I use `../` for routing files like js files, styles, etc. When I decided to apply `ScriptBundle` and replace `~/` instead `../` the website didn't work at.
js file completely are loaded on browser but they didn't work.
This is my code before `ScriptBundle` that work perfectly:

```
<!-- Page Scripts Starts -->
<script src="../Script/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/jquery.colorpanel.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/custom-navigation.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/custom-flex.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/custom-owl.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/custom-date-picker.js"></script>
<!-- Page Scripts Ends -->
```

and this is  after `ScriptBundle`:

```
<!-- Page Scripts Starts -->
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/Script/js") %>
<!-- Page Scripts Ends -->
```

Cs file:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Script/js").Include(
              "~/Script/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
              "~/Script/bootstrap.min.js",
              "~/Script/custom-date-picker.js",
              "~/Script/custom-flex.js",
              "~/Script/custom-navigation.js",
              "~/Script/custom-owl.js",
              "~/Script/jquery.colorpanel.js",
              "~/Script/jquery.flexslider.js",
              "~/Script/jquery.min.js",
              "~/Script/owl.carousel.min.js"));
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms/

Comment: That is beacuse the order of the script files (in .cs) is wrong. `jquery.min.js` should most likely be first. Change the order so that it is the same as per your working example. Since atleast all `jquery.*.js` files uses `jquery.min.js` they must be loaded after `jquery.min.js`.

Comment: didn't work doesn't give us any idea that what actually did not work. Kindly post what actually did not work. What was rendered in HTML when you used bundles?

Comment: `"~/Script/jquery.min.js"` must be on the first or topmost order. Other JS files should be ordered based from their dependency/importance.

Comment: @Sani Singh Huttunen -  Thank u so much it works. If you you want, put your post as a complete answer and I'll check it true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is beacuse the order of the script files (in .cs) is wrong. `jquery.min.js` should most likely be first. Change the order so that it is the same as per your working example. Since atleast all `jquery.*.js` files uses `jquery.min.js` they must be loaded after `jquery.min.js`.